# alpha & beta (for linear regression) calculations output nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I am new to Python and have been attempting to calculate the linear regression/Beta/Alpha for two securities, however my code is outputting Nan for both Beta & Alpha, and therefore I am unable to draw the regression line.

here is the code in question:

```
#calculate linear regression
beta_yPlt, alpha_yPlt = np.polyfit(xPlt, yPlt, 1)  # fit poly degree 1
print "Y Beta", beta_yPlt
print "Y Alpha", alpha_yPlt
plt.plot(xPlt, beta_yPlt * xPlt + alpha_yPlt, '-', color='red')
```

and here is the full script:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#inputs
symbols   = ['EUR=X', 'JPY=X']
startDate = datetime(2011,1,1)
endDate   = datetime(2016,12,31)

#get data from yahoo
instrument = DataReader(symbols, 'yahoo', startDate, endDate)
#isolate column
close = instrument['Adj Close']

#calculate daily returns
def compute_daily_returns(df):
    daily_returns = (df / df.shift(1)) - 1
    return daily_returns

dlyRtns = compute_daily_returns(close)
xPlt = dlyRtns[symbols[0]]
yPlt = dlyRtns[symbols[1]]

#draw "scatter plot" - using "o" workaround
dlyRtns.plot(x=symbols[0], y=symbols[1], marker='o', linewidth=0)

#calculate linear regression
beta_yPlt, alpha_yPlt = np.polyfit(xPlt, yPlt, 1)  # fit poly degree 1
print "Y Beta", beta_yPlt
print "Y Alpha", alpha_yPlt
plt.plot(xPlt, beta_yPlt * xPlt + alpha_yPlt, '-', color='red')

# Calculate correlation coefficient
print "Correlation", dlyRtns.corr(method='pearson')
plt.show()
```

and here is the output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Us/Desktop/untitled3/scatterPlot.py
Y Beta nan
Y Alpha nan
Correlation           EUR=X     JPY=X
EUR=X  1.000000  0.228223
JPY=X  0.228223  1.000000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any ideas why I getting Nan here? I am at a loss, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you perform the `shift` operation downwards, it's the first row that has `Nans`. You need to quantify those values for getting the regression coefficients. There are a total of 3 `Nans` in `xPlt` and `yPlt` respectively.

Comment: that did it, thanks --  adding the following line to my compute_daily_returns(df) function fixed the issue: daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0

Comment: But you still have 2 `Nans` each among `xPlt` and `yPlt`. You need to remove those too for the regression line to be displayed along with the scatter points. There are various ways to handle `Nans` such as `ffill`, `bfill`, even using sklearn's `Imputer` method.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to look into this, but it's a little confusing to me. In addition, I can not reproduce the data-pulling from yahoo on my current machine, so I can not run your code as it is.

Here a few questions and ideas:

- You should not name a variable `close`, since this word is used by Python. Sometimes (as in your example) it works anyway, but it's not good practice.
- Can you plot your data `xPlt` and `yPlt` separately, without anything else? I suspect that the error is in there.
- You call `DataReader` with an array of two values and save the output in `instrument`. Then you assign one column (chosen by name) to `close`, but in fact, there will be two columns named `Adj close`, right?

To cut a long story short: You should try to build up your code step by step, adding some `print` and `plot` commands after every step to see how the data that is saved in your variables looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot retrieve the data either.

My best guess: there are `nan`s or duplicate points in the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_daily_returns(df):
    daily_returns = (df / df.shift(1)) - 1
    daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0  
    return daily_returns
```

adding `daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0` fixed the issue, thanks to Nickil Maveli